# How to decrease GPU useage in XAML + Direct3D app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, directx, direct3d

I'm developing an app which uses Direct3D to draw routes on the Map.
I have noticed that my phone is so hot when shows Direct3D.
I have tried to reduce Draw calls to decrease GPU loading by set contentdirty at PrepareResource to false. So the Draw method is not called any more, unfortunately the phone still be hot one.

There is a way to reduce GPU usage?

```
HRESULT Direct3DInterop::PrepareResources(_In_ const LARGE_INTEGER* presentTargetTime, _Out_ BOOL* contentDirty)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(presentTargetTime);

    if (m_renderer != nullptr
        && m_renderer->IsDirty)
    {
        *contentDirty = true;
    }

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT Direct3DInterop::GetTexture(_In_ const DrawingSurfaceSizeF* size, _Inout_ IDrawingSurfaceSynchronizedTextureNative** synchronizedTexture, _Inout_ DrawingSurfaceRectF* textureSubRectangle)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(size);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(synchronizedTexture);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(textureSubRectangle);

    m_renderer->Render();
    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Is `*contentDirty` false by default? I can only see you setting it true. Also, have you checked if `m_renderer->IsDirty` is behaving correctly?

Comment: Yes I have checked the *contentDirty is false by default. I have checked the real Render method called correctly when it really required.